# What is a Intel LPC Interface Controller.

Tags: controller

Intel LPC Interface Controller,

What does LPC stand for?

for what is this interface used?

Answer (score 21):

LPC stand for [Low Pin Count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Pin_Count) - it is the chip used to connect all of the "legacy" PC components on motherboards.  For example it will control the PS/2, floppy, parallel and serial ports.

Before the LPC all of these devices were in the [ISA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture) bus and once boards stopped including them ISA slots, they switched to LPC because it was a simplifier interface for the small number of integrated devices they required.  It is named becaue it has a lower pin count than ISA.