# What is the usage of LPC socket on motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I have seen a 9-Pin socket on motherboard that is labeled LPC . What is the usage of this socket and which part can be connected to this socket ?

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/431913/what-is-a-intel-lpc-interface-controller except the socket is probably just because your board doesn't support any of the normal LPC-connected peripherals by default (i.e. no on-board IC connected to it) so the socket exists as an extension point if you need to add one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Intel LPC Interface Controller.](https://superuser.com/questions/431913/what-is-a-intel-lpc-interface-controller)